# Распознавание дорожных знаков по фотографии на смартфоне

Tags: алгоритм, распознавание-образов

Не знаете какой-нибудь несложный алгоритм распознавания дорожных знаков?

Т.к. дорожные знаки известны, то распознавание можно делать по шаблону. Алгоритм нужен такой, чтобы можно было в нём разобраться за не очень большое время и написать программу для смартфона (какая ОС для смартфона пока не известно, да и, думаю, не важно).

Потенциальная проблема: сравнение фотографии со всеми дорожными знаками возможно будет слишком долго обрабатываться смартфоном. Может есть по этому поводу какие-нибудь идеи? А может такое распознавание будет недолгим?

Comment: Алгоритм не подскажу, но мне кажется надо копать в сторону OpenCV - библиотечка где есть куча всего касательно компьютерного зрения, надо лишь написать скрипт для своей конкретной задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Слать на сервер, на котором работает `SIFT / SURF / ORB.`
- [Real-Time Traﬃc Sign Detection
  using Hierarchical Distance Matching](http://innovexpo.itee.uq.edu.au/2002/projects/s354244/thesis.pdf)
- [An overview of trafﬁc sign detection methods](http://www.fer.unizg.hr/_download/repository/BrkicQualifyingExam.pdf)
- И вся выдача гугла по [`traffic signs recognition algorithm.`](http://www.google.com/?q=traffic+signs+recognition+algorithm)
- `OpenCV` - не для смартфонов, т.к. под `ARM'ы` вы замучаетесь.

Comment: Котик_хочет_кушать@ 
А на смартфоне не получится? Просто сервер это еще больше работы.