# Распознавание объекта по фотографии [iOS, Swift]

Tags: ios, objective-c, изображения, opencv, swift1.2

Всем привет !

Передо мной появилась **задача**, с которой до этого никогда в жизни не встречался.

`Задача:` определить по фотографии (качество снимка может быть как и хорошим, так и плохим) объект.

`Цель:` с определенным объектом провести всяческие задачи (к примеру я хочу найти на фотографии собаку и определить ее цвет и породу).

`Платформа для реализации:` iOS

После парочки часов поиска информации в интернетах, я пришел к [такой вот статье](https://habrahabr.ru/post/208090/).

Автор всячески рассказывал про `OpenCV` и про группы последовательности:

1. предварительная фильтрация и подготовка изображения
2. логическая обработка результатов фильтрации
3. алгоритмы принятия решений на основе логической обработки

Я ознакомился с каждым этапом и сделал для себя некие выводы:

**1 пункт**
*для предварительной фильтрации я подумал, что лучше использовать* - `фильтрацию контуров` (контуры очень полезны, когда мы хотим перейти от работы с изображением к работе с объектами на этом изображении)

**2 пункт** 
*как логически обработать  результаты не имею ни малейшего понятия, но вроде бы* `контурный анализ` *решает мою проблему, но там нужны слишком идеальные условия* (которых у меня скорее всего не будет, а если и будут, то не всегда)

**3 пункт** - для меня остается загадкой.

**Вопрос:** в правильном направлении ли я иду ? То ли я вообще читаю. Может у меня очень глупые вопросы, но где как ни тут я смогу на них найти ответы.

P.S. нашел еще вот такое утверждение

> OpenCV - не для смартфонов, т.к. под ARM'ы вы замучаетесь.

Взятое [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/152874/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5)

***Всем огромное спасибо за внимание !***

Comment: Хм. Это задача под большой исследовательский проект. Есть в мире три-четыре реализации, вы хотите, чтобы кто-то написал прототип пятой?

Comment: @VladD нет, я не прошу о пятый прототип, я спросил в правильном направлении иду и ту ли литературу читаю, а так же - стоит ли браться за эту задачу одному или же эта задача более под группу программистов/математиков. Вроде хорошо сформулировал же вопрос, почему Вы язвите - не могу понять.

Comment: @kxxko , Вы всё же неверные задаёте вопросы. То ли, туда ли... всё это очень общие вопросы, столь же общие ответы на которые ни лично Вам, ни кому бы то ни было ещё пользы не принесут. Спрашивайте конкретику в практике, тогда Вам наверняка здесь помогут. Ну и конечно нет возможности не согласиться с Владом, что шансы на реализацию задуманного у Вас минимальны. Тем не менее лично я считаю, что это подчас и не главное - практический опыт он везде приветствуется. Пусть даже и негативный.

Comment: @alexis031182 спасибо за субъективную критику. Если на то уж пошло, то есть смысл закрыть вопрос.

Comment: @kxxko: Закрывать не стоит, но мне кажется, имеет смысл конкретизировать вопрос. Например, вы могли бы спросить, какова может быть/должна быть _архитектура_ подобного проекта. (Я не смогу ответить, но надеюсь, что другие участники смогут.)

Comment: @kxxko: Первая часть — распознавание контуров — достаточно простой шаг. А вот перейти [от контуров к конкретному понятию](http://cafehayek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/miracle_cartoon.jpg) (то есть, понять, что на данная кривая есть контур собачки, а не кошечки) — задача для искусственного интеллекта. Это не значит, что она принципиально нерешаемая, это значит, что она сложная.

Comment: Мне лично кажется, что задача под группу программистов и математиков, и хороший бюджет. Но может быть, уже есть открытые наработки, которые радикально упрощают задачу. Мне они не известны, но я и никогда не интересовался плотно этим вопросом.

Comment: @VladD спасибо огромное за помощь ! Оставлю вопрос, может кто нибудь будет сюда выкладывать свои предположения. А если я по-немногу буду находить ответы на свои вопросы, я могу тут дополнять ответами или же не стоит ?

Comment: @kxxko: Мне кажется, стоит. Задача сложная и нетривиальная, и если вы найдёте решение, хотя бы частичное, оно заинтересует многих. (Возможно, лучше один ответ с обновлениями.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если кратко, то в задаче распознавания программный инструментарий всегда должен подбираться под конкретный тип объекта. Если разговор начинается со слов, мол, а не найти, да не распознать ли нам что угодно, что только в кадр попадёт, то ну её нафиг такую задачу. Не придуман пока ещё универсальный классификатор объектов. Даже если некое ПО позволяет отыскивать произвольные объекты, то на самом деле это целый комплекс различных решений и алгоритмов, собранных воедино.

Далее следует рассмотреть, а что за тип объекта предлагается к распознаванию. Какова его геометрическая форма/формы. С каких ракурсов будет вестись съёмка. Сильны ли перепады освещения. Объект в движении или статичен. Имеется ли набор (обычно "набор" эквивалентен сотням тысяч и более образцов) изображений для обучения машины. И ещё много других условий и нюансов. Даже такой, казалось бы, тривиальный для человека объект как собака, порождает множество вариаций. К примеру: в кадре будет только морда (анфас, профиль, вообще вверх ногами) или вся тушка целиком, окрас, а что насчёт шерсти (какие-то породы полохматистее, какие-то менее), и тому подобное.

Все эти различия абсолютно принципиальны практически для любого алгоритма распознавания, который захочется применить. Какой-то из них будет нечувствителен к окрасу и оттенкам, но будет чувствителен к ракурсу съёмки. Какой-то будет нечувствителен к поворотам и наклонам, но абсолютно чувствителен к форме объекта.

Контурный анализ - прекрасный выбор, но, как верно уже было отмечено в вопросе, слишком грешит необходимостью наличия так называемых идеальных условий. В случае с собакой идеальными условиями будет равномерно облить её всю какой-нибудь краской, например, красной и посадить в помещение с белым полом и стенами. Вместо мигающих ламп установить по углам прожекторы, дающие ровный и немигающий свет. После этого нужно заставить измученное невыносимыми условиями животное сидеть смирно и не двигаться, чтобы геометрическая форма контуров, которые будут обнаружены в кадре, менялись в незначительных пределах. Разумеется, что ПО, полученное в ходе такого эксперимента, сможет распознавать только красных собак, сидящих в белой комнате с прожекторами. Да и вообще профит сомнительный, ведь стоит лишь только слегка облегчить условия, сделав их для контурного анализа менее идеальными, как такой алгоритм тут же перестанет работать.

Контуры - это двумерная форма. Это, по сути, малое количество информации к обработке, что с одной стороны ведёт к экономии вычислительных ресурсов и увеличению скорости работы алгоритма, но с другой это и отсутствие неких признаков, без которых в отдельных случаях распознавание становится попросту невозможно.

[image: первая цифра]
[image: вторая цифра]

Попробуйте угадать, где на картинках цифра 1, а где 7. А может быть там две единицы или две семёрки... смотря с какого угла смотреть и какой шрифт использовать...

Очевидно, что контурный анализ не подходит для распознавания таких объектов как собака (да любых, у которых форма не есть константа) и для тех случаев, когда объекты могут быть деформированы, что для естественной среды - норма.

Вообще получается интересная штука: как если бы жители двумерного мира пытались смотреть на трёхмерные объекты. Куб для них предстал бы квадратом, а шар - кругом. Вот и камера видит совсем не то, что способен моделировать человеческий мозг, добавляя необходимые детали, которые не увидели глаза, самостоятельно. Об этом необходимо помнить.

Comment: Перед тем, как поставить галочку за ответ, я пару раз прочитал Ваш ответ, что бы лучше вникнуть. Спасибо за уделенное время, может показаться кому то, что ответ не полный или еще что нибудь, но мне он дал немалое понятие ! Спасибо огромное за Ваши старания. Картина в целом ясна, проблемы ясны. Буду пробовать =) Уверен, что ничего не получится, но если получится - это будет лучшее достижение на данном этапе моей жизни. Спасибо !